# Updating/Adding subscribers through api

Tags: soap-api

### Updating/Adding Subscriber Through API.

I am looking or a set of rules to update/add subscribers through the api. There seems to be the following scenarios.

- Update/add using subscriber id
- Update/add using subscriber key

---

1. Ideally we want to do updates using  subscriber id as this is just a number and we should have it most of the time. Do we need to set subscriber key and email address for the update?
2. On occasion we may have new subscriber information which we will be adding. 
   If subscriber key is enabled this is required, do we need to set email address as well?
   If subscriber key is not enabled we set must set email address  and subscriber key to be the same   value and do the add.

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: can you clarify which product you're using, is this ExactTarget?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can update by the subscriber id so long as you also set the "IDSpecified" flag.
2. EmailAddress is required when creating Subscribers regardless if SubscriberKey is enabled. If SubscriberKey is the email address, just set them both to the same property.

See [Creating Subscribers](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_subscriber/)